# Trying to retrieve LineNumber information from NJsonSchema ValidationErrors?

Tags: njsonschema

I need to do some json schema validation and am using NJsonSchema because I cannot get the license for Json.Net Schema. Is there a way to get LineNumber information for the ValidationErrors?

It looks like the only properties available are

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the error kind.
    public ValidationErrorKind Kind { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the property path.
    public string Path { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the property name.
    public string Property { get; }
```

Comment: Please create an issue on the project's site...

Comment: This feature is now implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update http://NJsonSchema.org, this feature is now implemented...